# Move to Sd not working after upload to Market

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I've implemented all the necessary things for "Move To SD card" functionality and the app can be moved to the SD card when launched from Eclipse or if I manually install the .apk file on the phone. However, after I've uploaded the apk to the Market, I've downloaded the app and "Move To SD" button was disabled.
The app is called "[redacted]".

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:installLocation="preferExternal" >

    ...
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

What could be wrong with it?

Comment: I have installed your app, and it automatically installed to SD card. So it works. Maybe your android device has version less than 2.2?

Comment: Hm, great. Thank you. It seems that it is an issue with "my TV". As for your question - i'm running 2.2.1 and if I install the app from an APK, it's working fine. Strange thing :)

Comment: In other words, sounds like my suggestion was correct, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the button isn't grayed out because the app already is on your SD card?

When you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be installed on the external storage as the default.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. My application can be moved to sd card before uploading to google play, but after its been uploaded and downloaded from Google Play, the Move to SD card button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:installLocation="auto"` in manifest

**Example**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mamlambo.article.phrasebook" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.1"  
 android:installLocation="auto">
```

set minimum sdk version as 8. Because this feature is supported in android 2.2

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Comment: I've tried "auto" first but it didn't work, so then I've switched to "preferExternal". However, jamapag has installed the app and he says it was installed on the SD card. So everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three things to check.

1. installLocation="auto" in AndroidManifest.xml as you stated above.
2. Set target sdk version to at least 8
3. Make sure Copy Protection is OFF in the Android Developer Console, under Product Details

Comment: Is the 3rd step needed NOW? as my olders apps have copy protection ON but still can be moved to SD Card, its just my latest app which is having problem.